# Find related HTML tags with javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to find related HTML tags with javascipt. I try some thinks with regular expression but without success.

Example html:

```html
<span>Hello <span>World</span></span><span>How are you</span>
```

I want to find

```html
<span>Hello <span>World</span></span>
```

and

```html
<span>How are you</span>
```

But NOT the whole and not

```html
<span>Hello <span>World</span>
```

My trys:

```regex
/<(\w+)(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>(.*)<\/\1>/gmi
```

and

```regex
/<(\w+)(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>(.*?)<\/\1>/gmi
```

And a view other thinks I dont remember.

Comment: You should never use regex for HTML parsing due to its potentially complex nested structure. Regex is not well-suited for this purpose. Try using an HTML parser instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I think a paser does not help me. I want to find all html tag not only span tags

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by related tags. If you want to just extract the elements by a tag name then you may consider using `document.getElementsByTagName` function or `querySelector`. But to achieve what you have presented in your example above you can just filter the children of a container.

Have a look at the code examples:

```js
// Example 1: only spans
const EXAMPLE_1 = document.getElementById('example1')

let relatedA = [...EXAMPLE_1.children].filter(x => x.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'SPAN')
console.log(relatedA.map(x => x.outerHTML))

// Example 2: only A and marked as related
const EXAMPLE_2 = document.getElementById('example2')

let relatedB = [...EXAMPLE_2.querySelectorAll('a, .related')]
console.log(relatedB.map(x => x.outerHTML))
```

```html
<div id="example1">
    <span>Hello <span>World</span></span>
    <span>How are you?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab voluptas perferendis enim dolores ad reprehenderit aliquam id ut doloremque aut laboriosam, consequuntur labore in amet cupiditate? Voluptatibus, ipsa beatae aliquid.</p>
    <span>I'm fine, thanks!</span>
</div>

<div id="example2">
    <a href="#">A</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam distinctio alias vel quo consectetur in rem eum, aut animi quidem at molestias esse architecto quisquam, itaque sit velit eligendi eius!</p>
    <a href="#">B</a>
    <p class="related">C</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni aspernatur libero aliquid maiores reiciendis, quam culpa, mollitia harum molestiae, quos aut. Laborum molestias aliquid ipsum. Dolorum impedit expedita, sunt odio!</p>
    <a href="#">D</a>
    <a href="#">E</a>
</div>
```